# how to replace substring at the end of string using SQL?

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle, sql-update

I have data in a table like this:

```
xxx-xxxxxxx-29
xxx-xxxxxx-87
xxx-xxxxxxxxx-2
xxx-xxx-33
```

I need to replace every -n at the end with -0n (to add a zero between the dash and the number).
Leave -nn as it is.

So, if 2nd character from the right is '-' replace it with '-0'

can this be done using UPDATE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to replace every `-n` at the end with `-0n` (to add a zero between the dash and the number).

One option is to use `regexp_replace()`:

```
update mytable set mycol = regexp_replace(mycol, '-(\d)$', '-0\1');
```

`'-(\d)$'` matches on a dash followed by a one digit at the end of the string, and captures the digit; you can then prepend a leading `'0'`.

Comment: @GMB `'-(\d)$'` is good one +1. On a large data set, a where condition would be more efficient in performance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
update mytable
set data = substr(data, 1, length(data)-1) || '0' || substr(data,-1)
where data like '%-_';
```